# Is it possible to tell if a type overrides the default trait implementation?

Tags: rust

Here I have a trait with two functions, both with a default implementation. Is there any way to tell which functions have the default implementation and which are overridden for each of the types?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3239e7faa9fb5117e32afe7ae43c687

I thought I could compare the address of the function, but it seems each type gets it's own unique function pointer, regardless. Did I do it right?

You might ask why I might want to do such a thing in the first place. It's for a plugin system. Each plugin can override a subset of functions on the Plugin trait, but when registering the plugin I want to know which trait functions the plugin implements (as opposed to just has the default implementation.)

Probably this can be done by making the register function a macro?

Comment: Could you have the trait function itself return `Option<fn()>`? Then you could have the trait default implementation return `None` and any custom implementations would return `Some(real_impl_fn)` or something.

Comment: I could do that, but I think it gets suboptimal when fn is async and requires state (a shared reference to the struct implementing the plugin.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function pointers will not be reliable because of compiler optimizations. For example, if you build in release you will see the same address for `<C as Foo>::bar` and `<C as Foo>::baz` because the compiler combined them since they contain the same body ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=56b2ebb1232f34d849c0fc48693accbe))

A macro could generate other functions like `fn override_foo() -> bool { true }` and make it possible to determine if it has been overridden, but for a plugin system, I would probably stick to function pointers wrapped in `Option<T>` and pass in a struct.